# Motivations for ontological pluralism – suggested reading?

Tags: reference-request, ontology

I’m looking for suggested reading on ontological pluralism.

There are so many contested entities (?) like numbers, holes, the poems of Lord Byron, universals, various types of non-existent objects (Pegasus, round square cupola on Berkeley college) etc. all with their respective protracted philosophical discourse…

But I’m more interested in a broad overview…

It does not have to be too serious. A kind of tour of paradoxes, which supposedly result from ontological monism, would suffice. Like W. V. O. Quine’s *“On What There Is,”* but with a different message (ok, maybe that is too high a standard to meet).

Comment: Richard Routley: On what there is not. Philosophy and Phenomenological Research 43 (1982), 151-177.

Comment: [Turner, Ontological Pluralism](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25700478), [Cotnoir-Edwards, From Truth Pluralism to Ontological Pluralism](https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/~ac117/papers/TPOP.pdf) survey some positions and arguments in analytic philosophy. [Latour's Inquiry into Modes of Existence](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/an-inquiry-into-modes-of-existence-an-anthropology-of-the-moderns/) is a continental take with a radically different "message". [Vila Pérez](https://revistas.unbosque.edu.co/index.php/rcfc/article/view/1276) gives an interesting critique in view of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Conifold Latour’s first chapter is about … climate change.